# Selenium: IsTextPresent. Is text "abc" present in text "abcd"?

Tags: c#, selenium

```
string searchText = "test this";

Sel.Type("//*[@id='txtbox']", searchText);
Sel.Click("//*[id='goButton']");

string highlightedTermsInResultsPage = Sel.GetText("//*[@id='searchTermMatch']"); //returns "test"
```

How can I compare `searchText` and `highlightedTermsInResultsPage` using `IsElementPresent()` method? I want to check if `highlightedTermsInResultsPage` matches part of `searchText` or whole `searchText`.

Comment: What do you mean by compare using isElementPresent? You should retrieve the text using getText and then compare it using your programming language rather than selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but maybe you can do

```
Sel.isElementPresent("//*[contains(child::text(), '" + searchText + "') and @id= 'searchTermMatch'])
```